# What does #53 mean in nslookup nameserver address result?

Tags: nameserver, nslookup

When I run this:

```
nslookup some.host.com
```

I get results like this:

```
Server:         4.2.2.1
Address:        4.2.2.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   some.host.com
Address: #.#.#.#
```

"4.2.2.1" is at the top of my /etc/resolv.conf, so that makes sense, but what does the `#53` mean? Googling around, this seems to be commonly appended to the address here in nslookup results, but I can't find any information about what it actually means.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's the port number used for [DNS request](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd197515%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).